# Agrupar dados de uma tabela

Tags: php, mysql

tenho a seguinte instrução sql:

```
Select 

Notas.NotaID,
Materias.MateriaNome, 
Alunos.AlunoNome,  
Alunos.AlunoID,
   max(case when NotaBimestre = 1 then Nota else null end) as 1bim,
   max(case when NotaBimestre = 2 then Nota else null end) as 2bim,
   max(case when NotaBimestre = 3 then Nota else null end) as 3bim,
   max(case when NotaBimestre = 4 then Nota else null end) as 4bim

From ((notas 
INNER JOIN Materias 
   ON Notas.MateriaID = Materias.MateriaID) 
INNER JOIN Alunos
   ON Notas.AlunoID = Alunos.AlunoID)      

group by (NotaID)
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para ficar nesse padrão:

```
ID | ALUNO    | DISCIPLINA           | 1BIM| 2BIM | 3BIM | 4BIM
16 | NATANAEL | BANCO DE DADOS       | 8   |      |      | 
17 | GUSTAVO  | PROGRAMAÇÃO PARA WEB | 9.5 | 8    | 8.5  | 10
```

Comment: Qual SGBD você está utilizando?

Comment: Você vai precisar consultar a tabela de notas 1 vez para cada bimestre, não percorrer ela apenas uma única vez como está na sua consulta. Recomendo usar subqueries para tal

Comment: Tire o "nota id" do GROUP BY.

Comment: @Motta não vai adiantar porque ele precisa verificar o bimestre. No caso ele terá que fazer uma tabela com os valores e depois realizar um `PIVOT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considerando que seu `SGBD` seja o `SQL Server` você pode reunir os dados em uma `subquery` e realizar o `PIVOT` em cima desses dados:

```
SELECT a.alunonome AS aluno,
       m.materianome AS disciplina,
       y.bim1,
       y.bim2,
       y.bim3,
       y.bim4,
  FROM (
    SELECT n.materiaid,
           n.alunoid,
           'bim' + CAST(n.notabimestre AS VARCHAR) as semestre,
           n.nota
      FROM notas n
  ) x
  PIVOT (AVG(x.nota) FOR semestre IN (bim1, bim2, bim3, bim4)) y
  INNER JOIN materias m ON m.materiaid = y.materiaid
  INNER JOIN alunos a ON a.alunoid = y.alunoid
```

Caso esteja utilizando o `MySQL`, você pode agrupar utilizando `CASE` e ajustando o `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT a.alunonome AS aluno,
       m.materianome AS disciplina,
       AVG(CASE n.notabimestre
             WHEN 1 THEN n.nota
           END) AS bim1,
       AVG(CASE n.notabimestre
             WHEN 2 THEN n.nota
           END) AS bim2,
       AVG(CASE n.notabimestre
             WHEN 3 THEN n.nota
           END) AS bim3,
       AVG(CASE n.notabimestre
             WHEN 4 THEN n.nota
           END) AS bim4
  FROM nota n
 INNER JOIN materias m ON m.materiaid = n.materiaid
 INNER JOIN alunos a ON a.alunoid = n.alunoid
 GROUP BY n.materiaid, n.alunoid, a.alunonome, m.materianome
```

> [`AVG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg)
>
> Returns the average value of expr... If there are no matching rows, AVG() returns NULL.

Em tradução livre:

> Retorna o valor médio da expressão... Se não houverem linhas, AVG() retornará NULL.

---

**Observação:** Notei que você utilizou a função `MAX`para obter as notas mas acredito que o ideal no seu caso é utilizar o `AVG`, já que o que interessa é a média.

Comment: Muito bom Sorack! Me ajudou aqui

Comment: @SmokeRohden disponha. Se possível adicione qual o SGBD nas tags da pergunta, por favor

Comment: Se caso eu quiser mostrar o ID da nota referente ao bimestre teria como?

Comment: @SmokeRohden Só se você concatenar, já que são 1 para vários

Answer (score 1):

O seu SELECT não pode iniciar na tabela Notas, tem que iniciar em alunos, e fazer um SUB-SELECT para cada bimestre, mais ou menos dessa forma:

```
 SELECT b.MateriaNome, a.AlunoNome, a.AlunoID,
        (SELECT MAX(Nota) FROM Notas WHERE NotaBimestre = 1 AND MateriaId = b.MateriaId AND AlunoId = a.AlunoId) AS '1bim',
        (SELECT MAX(Nota) FROM Notas WHERE NotaBimestre = 2 AND MateriaId = b.MateriaId AND AlunoId = a.AlunoId) AS '2bim',
        (SELECT MAX(Nota) FROM Notas WHERE NotaBimestre = 3 AND MateriaId = b.MateriaId AND AlunoId = a.AlunoId) AS '3bim',
        (SELECT MAX(Nota) FROM Notas WHERE NotaBimestre = 4 AND MateriaId = b.MateriaId AND AlunoId = a.AlunoId) AS '4bim',
    FROM Alunos a
    INNER JOIN Materias b
    GROUP BY a.AlunoID, b.MateriaId;
```